# Get the name and properties of controls dynamically

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have 10 TrackBar1 TrackBar2, TrackBar3 ..... TrackBar10. What I want is how to manipulate it.

I Have problem with access to TrackBar control property Min, Max, Value ....

```vb
For i = 1 to 10

  ' its OK
  Me.Controls("TrackBar" & i.ToString("0")).Text = "Test1"

  ' Error -Min is not a member "System.Windows.Forms.Control"
  Me.Controls("TrackBar" & i.ToString("0")).Min = 10      

Next
```

Comment: You have to cast it.  `DirectCast(Me.Controls("TrackBar" & i.ToString("0")), TrackBar).Minimum = 10`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you index the `Controls` collection, you get a `Control` reference back. That collection can store any type of control, so the only thing that they all have in common is that they inherit the `Control` class.  That means that you can access any members of the `Control` class directly.  `Text` is a member of the `Control` class so you can access the `Text` property directly.  Any members that are more specific than that require a cast as the more specific type in order to access them.  If you want to access members of the `TrackBar` class then you need a reference of type `TrackBar` rather than type `Control`, which means casting as that type.

```
Dim c = Me.Controls("TrackBar" & i)
Dim t = DirectCast(c, TrackBar)
```

To explain casting, I always use the example of taking a pet to the vet.  A vet can treat all types of animals but, when you take your pet, it is a specific type of animal.  When you present a box to the vet, all they know is that there's an animal inside, so all they know that they can do for it is the things that apply to all animals.  Once you take your pet out of the box and they see what type of animal it is, they then know that they can do all the things specific to that type of animal.  Your pet didn't magically change from one type to another but the vet now knows all the specific things it can do for it as well as the general.

That's how casting in programming works.  Your `TrackBar` was always a `TrackBar` but, because it was initially accessed via a `Control` reference, the compiler only knew that it can do things with it that are common to all controls.  The cast informs the compiler of the specific type so the compiler knows that it can do things with it specific to that type.

One option to avoid the explicit cast is to just get the `TrackBars` in the first place:

```
For Each tb In Me.Controls.OfType(Of TrackBar)()
    'Use tb here.
Next
```

The `OfType` method will filter out all items not of the specified type and will return references of the specified type, so `tb` is type `TrackBar` in that code.  You'd have to use a `For Each` loop in this case, so you have less control over the order the items are accessed.  They will be returned in accordance with the z-order on the form.  That means that if you added them in ascending numerical order, which seems likely, and did not change the z-order, you'll still get them back in ascending numerical order.

Comment: Thank you for the perfect explanation. Your example works for me. 

I would like to ask you one more piece of advice. I have TrackBar1 in GroubBox1, TrackBar2 in GroupBox2 .... TrackBar10 in GroupBox10.  

If I use  

`i = index  
       dim c = Me.GroupBox2.Controls ("TrackBar" & i)  
       Dim t = DirectCast (c, TrackBar)  
`
Please how to edit  

**Me.GroupBox1.Controls ("TrackBar" & i)**  

to replace **GroupBox1** with an index  

Thank you

Comment: You already know how. If you can get `TrackBars` 1 to 10 from `Me.Controls` then you can get `GroupBoxes` 1 to 10. As I have already said, indexing a `Controls` collection gives you a `Control` reference, so you can access all members of that type directly. `Controls` is a member of that type, so you can then get the `TrackBar` by name from the `Controls` collection of the `GroupBox`.

Comment: That said, you don't actually have to care about the `GroupBoxes`. The `Find` method of the form's `Controls` collection can get nested controls by name, so you can get the `TrackBars` directly from the form. Just note that `Find` returns an array, because there may be controls at different levels with the same name. If you only have one control with each name, you just need to get the first element from that array.